# Can $\oint_{|z|=2}z^3 \bar {z} e^\frac{1}{(z-1)} dz$ be solved?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

How we can calculate the result of following Integral?

$$\oint_{|z|=2}z^3 \bar {z} e^\frac{1}{z-1} \mathrm{d}z$$

Comment: Hi! Can you please show what you've tried so far or where you're stuck?

Comment: The function inside is not holomorphic, and furthermore $e^{1/z-1}$ is an essential singularity, so as far as I know the residue formula cannot be applied. You might be able to find the answer directly, though, by parametrizing the curve and using standard integration tricks.

Comment: @MattAllegro Short answer in my note is $13 \pi i / 3$

Comment: @AlexZorn please make me direct hint. this is not well formed for me but in my note this has a short answer.

Comment: Just an observation: $|z|=2$ implies $z\bar z=4$, so the integral is equal to $\oint_{|z|=2}4z^2 e^\frac{1}{z-1} \mathrm{d}z$. This is holomorphic except at the essential singularity $z=1$, so computing the Laurent series around $z=1$ should give you the relevant residue needed to compute the integral.

Comment: @DejanGovc is right.

Comment: @DejanGovc I know it but In fact my problem is put all thing together. I'm so glad if you learn me .

Comment: @SaraNia, do your answer $13\pi i/3$ include the factor $4$ from $|z|^2$? Including that factor $4$, I get $4\times \frac{13\pi i}{3} = \frac{52\pi i}{3}$.

Comment: @achillehui some of our friends calculate your last answer :) what is the final answer ? which one is correct :)

Comment: @SaraNia $\frac{52\pi i}{3}$, looks like Dr. MV has fixed his/her answer.

Comment: @achillehui I believe that we are correct   ... at long last!

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm sure we are correct. I evaluate the contour integral using its residue at $z = \infty$ and get the same answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z=2|} z^3\bar z e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)}}dz&=\oint_{|z=2|} 4z^2 e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)}}dz\\
&=8\pi i \text{Res}_{z=1}\left(z^2 e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)}}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

The residue $\text{Res}_{z=1} \left(z^2 e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)}}\right)$ can be found as follows

Note that $z^2=(z-1)^2+2(z-1)+1$ and the Laurent expansion of $e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}$ is

$$e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)}}=1+\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{(z-1)^3}+ \cdots$$

wherein we observe that the residue at $z=1$ of $z^2e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)}}$ comes from the 3 terms

$$\begin{align}
&(1)\,\,(z-1)^2 \times \frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{(z-1)^3}=\frac16 (z-1)^{-1}\\
&(2)\,\,2(z-1) \times \frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}=1 (z-1)^{-1}\\
&(3)\,\, 1 \times \frac{1}{z-1}=1 (z-1)^{-1}
\end{align}$$

Thus the residue is $\frac16+1+1=\frac{13}{6}$.  Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z=2|} z^3\bar z e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)}}dz&=\oint_{|z=2|} 4z^2 e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)}}dz\\
&=8\pi i \text{Res}_{z=1}\left(z^2 e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)}}\right)\\
&=8\pi i \frac{13}{6}\\
&=\frac{52\pi i}{3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: my last answer is $13 \pi i /3$

Comment: How did you arrive at that answer?

Comment: short answer in my note.

Comment: Where did you obtain the note?

Comment: The Copy from my Professor Book.

Comment: Are you certain that is the professor's result of the value of this integral?

Comment: not sure. I try to prove your answer.

Comment: Your professor appears to have missed a factor of $4$ from the term $z\bar z=|z|^2=4$ on the contour of integration.

Comment: some typo is here.

Comment: What typo do you mean?

Comment: now okey let me to evaluate it

Comment: Glad I could help here Sara!

Comment: you are so kind !

Comment: It was my pleasure!